# SystemBar/BottomBar in Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

Sorry for my bad english.

I develop a game in which will be implemented autoOrientation, but when i rotate device and stage orientation is changed, then reinitialization process take too long time (because i use GPU to render game content), therefore i decided to disable autoOrientation and manually calculate the orientation of the device from accelerometer data, and then rotate the main game sprite accordingly to calculated orientation...and it works, but SystemBar remains static in its first position when game was launched. The question is how to set SystemBar position in Android, something like this

SetBarPosition(TOP / BOTTOM / RIGHT / LEFT);

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should handle the orientation change yourself instead of disabling it. On android you should implement onConfigurationChanged() method and add to manifest that you handle orientation changes.